# linux do not send IRK value(Identity Information) and 'Identity Address Information' to peripheral when BLE SMP pairing

Tags: linux, bluez

I'm using the kernel version 4.2.0 with bluez-5.35 in linux.

I'm programming use bluez dbus communication only.

When BLE SMP pairing, our system do not send 'Identity Information (Identity Resolving Key)' and 'Identity Address Information (AddrType, BD_ADDR)' to peripheral device(Roche ACCU-CHEK Performa Connect).

How can I do for SMP pairing success?

Attached image is shown SMP process between our central and peripheral.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use BlueZ as the Master side, normally the "privacy feature" that uses an IRK to generate random BD addresses is not used. Instead the public BD address is used. That means you don't need an IRK in order to identify the master.

What do you mean that you want "SMP pairing success"? Is something failing with the current setup?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

When I try pairing with peripheral device(Roche ACCU-CHEK Performa Connect),
Bluez DBus send signals 'Paired : true' 'Connected : true' But the peripheral device show pairing fail message.
So, after pairing process, I can read charateristics values but RACP opCode Opreator write is fail because of 'Not Paired'.
I think according to 'Transport Specific Key Distribution' in Bluetooth spec. Master have to send 'Identity Information (Identity Resolving Key)' and 'Identity Address Information (AddrType, BD_ADDR)' to slave regardless of BT address type.

Comment: IRK and identity address information is only sent if requested. In the initial pairing request and response messages, it's exchanged which messages should be sent.